# VBA 1 лишний байт при записи в бинарный файл

Tags: vba, office, макросы

При использовании оператора `Put` возникает странная ситуация - размер записываемого в файл массива 10 байт, однако в конец файла всегда добавляется 1 нулевой байт. Как это исправить?

```
Dim arr(10) As Byte
Open strFilePath For Binary Lock Write As #1
Put #1, , arr
Close #1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никаких лишних нулей `Put` не пишет. Здесь дело в `Option Base 0` по умолчанию [см. здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement).
Если явно не указать нижнюю границу массива `Dim arr(10) As Byte` при `Option Base 0` (по умолчанию), то объявится массив от 0 до 10, т.е. из 11 элементов.
Чтобы задать 10 элементов при верхней границе 10, явно определите `Option Base 1` или укажите нижнюю и верхнюю границы при объявлении массива `Dim arr(1 To 10) As Byte`.
Ну или `Dim arr(9) As Byte` - будет также 10 байт от 0 до 9.

```
Option Base 1

Sub test1()
    strFilePath = "c:\test\binary.bin"

    Dim arr(1 To 10) As Byte
    Dim f, i

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = i
    Next
    
    f = FreeFile
    Open strFilePath For Binary Lock Write As f
    Put f, , arr
    Close f
End Sub
```

Файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечание.  Для нахождения свободного номера файла можно использовать функцию [FreeFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/freefile-function)

Comment: `Dim f` не хватает

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, которую вы описываете, связана с тем, что оператор Put в Visual Basic добавляет нулевой байт в конец файла при записи массива, чтобы обозначить его конец. Это поведение по умолчанию для оператора Put в режиме бинарной записи.

Если вы хотите избежать добавления нулевого байта в конец файла, вам нужно использовать другие методы записи, такие как использование функций FilePut или PutObject. Ниже приведен пример использования функции FilePut для записи массива байтов без добавления нулевого байта в конец файла:

```
Dim arr(10) As Byte
Open strFilePath For Binary Lock Write As #1
FilePut(1, arr)
Close #1
```

При использовании FilePut нулевой байт не будет добавлен в конец файла, и файл будет содержать только указанные вами 10 байт.

Comment: Ошибка: `FilePut - sub or function not defined`

Comment: Данный способ рабочий, но медленный: `For i = 1 To UBound(arr)     Put #1, LOF(1) + 1, arr(i)     Next`

Comment: Оба решения **не подходят**